# how can my code 'pass' if it doesnt find a word in csv python

Tags: python, csv, if-statement, conditional-statements

here is my code.csv

```
one,two #read the headers from here, and if the code finds headers, 
1,2     #it takes the columns of the old headers, to the new headers in a new order.
2,3
3,4
```

for example, the output.csv would look like this:

```
new_two,new_one,new_three
2,1
3,2
4,3
```

notice there is missing the ",three" after two. This is my python code:

```
import csv

with open('code.csv', 'rb') as input, open('result.csv', 'wb') as output:
        reader = csv.DictReader(input)
        rows = [row for row in reader]
        writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',')

        writer.writerow(["new_two", "new_one", "new_three"])

        for row in rows:
                if row['one'] and row['two'] and row['three'] not in row:
                        pass
                else:
                        writer.writerow([row["one"], row["two"], row["three"]])
```

Basically i want my code to always have this part: `writer.writerow([row["one"], row["two"], row["three"]])`, that takes the columns from input file headers, but if it doesn't find one of those headers,I want it to forget that and continue on with the rest of the columns.

it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_code.py", line 11, in <module>
    if row['one'] and row['two'] and row['three'] not in row:
KeyError: 'three'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While syntactically valid, the

```
row['one'] and row['two'] and row['three'] not in row
```

doesn't do what you are expecting it to.

To check that `row` contains the keys `'one'`, `'two'` and `'three'`, use

```
if 'one' in row and 'two' in row and 'three' in row:
   writer.writerow([row['one'], row['two'], row['three']])
```

In case you're wondering about your original code, the `if` is parsed as

```
if (row['one']) and (row['two']) and (row['three'] not in row):
```

In other words, the `row['one']` and `row['two']` are treated as separate expressions that are ANDed together. This clearly isn't what you want. Besides, you've got your ANDs and ORs mixed up (my version uses AND because I've reversed the check, placing the `writerow()` in the `if` rather than the `else`).

Comment: Your code worked almost. It now prints out 
new_two,new_one,new_three
1,2,['three']
2,3,['three']
3,4,['three']
while i want the output to be 
new_two,new_one,new_three
1,2
2,3
3,4